# How to clone message in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.1.2.0

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

How can we achieve cloning message in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.1.2.0
Earlier it was in Microsoft service bus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Clone()` method is not there anymore. Instead you can use the new [constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusMessage__ctor_Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusReceivedMessage_) that takes a recieved message.

Comment: Weird that this question is closed, it and this answer were exactly what I needed.